# Deserialize a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to deserialize a list of a model that looks like this :

```
public class GlobalSearchModel
{
     public List<ProductionModel> ProductionOrder { get; set; }
     public List<ItemModel> Item { get; set; }
     public List<LayoutModel> Layout { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do it there:

```
[HttpGet("[Action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery]string code, bool layout, bool item, bool production)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("GlobalSearch?elementSearch={0}&itemBool={1}&layoutBool={2}&productionBool={3}", code, item, layout, production));

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        List<GlobalSearchModel> search = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GlobalSearchModel>>(jsonString);

        return Json(search);
    }
    else
        return View();
}
```

But the Json returned to me is this::

```
[{"productionOrder":null,"item":null,"layout":null}]
```

I set a breakpoint on the variable `JsonString` and I have a response but I can't use it.

The return of the JsonString look is :

```
[{\"itemlist\":[{\"Id\":0,\"ItemCode\":\"1235\",\"ItemVariant\":null,\"Modified\":null,\"ModifiedBy\":null,\"ReasonId\":null,\"ReasonComment\":null,\"Type\":null}],\"productionlist\":[],\"LayoutsList\":[]}]
```

Comment: Please provide the JSON you're receiving before deserializing.

Comment: So what's the content of `jsonString`? Are you sure you should be deserializing to a `List<GlobalSearchModel>` rather than a single `GlobalSearchModel`? It sounds like the immediate problem isn't actually in ASP.NET Core - it would be good to show a console application with hard-coded JSON which tries to deserialize. That would make it really easy for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Forgive me if you've cut out a chunk of code for the question - but you are deserializing into `search` variable then serializing straight away in `return Json(search);`. Couldn't you just `return jsonString;`?

Comment: I update the issue and I can't work on the jsonString

Comment: Even if `\"` is because you copied the debugger display rather than the actual string, your JSON looks nothing like your C# object. This is the source of your problems.

Comment: It would be worth clarifying whether the backslashes are *actually* in the JSON string. I strongly suspect they're not, and that you've copied that from the debugger - it's really unfortunate that the debugger is misleading like this. If the string is actually that JSON but without the backslashes, then the problem is the name of the properties: you're expecting `ProductionOrder`, `Item` and `Layout` whereas you've got `itemList`, `productionList` and `LayoutsList`.

Comment: I don't know cause I'm new on asp.net core and c#.